# Read rows and columns from excel in Python and put them in array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, export-to-csv, xlrd

My aim is to read excel data and then classify each first name as first name, second name as second name and domain as domain variables respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over rows with `pandas`, update data and then save it to excel with `pandas` again:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', index_col=None)

output = {'0': [], '1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    output['0'].append(f"{row['First']}@{row['Domain']}")
    output['1'].append(f"{row['Second']}@{row['Domain']}")
    output['2'].append(f"{row['First']}{row['Second']}@{row['Domain']}")
    output['3'].append(f"{row['First']}.{row['Second']}@{row['Domain']}")
    output['4'].append(f"{row['First'][0]}{row['Second']}@{row['Domain']}")

df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=list(output.keys()))
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but isn't this going to be very inefficient if there are 10,000+ rows? Wouldn't I have to initialize 10k arrays. Is there an faster way for that?

Comment: sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: sorry, have no idea about faster way of doing it. probably use c++

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want something like that :

```
df = pandas.read_excel("input.xlsx")

def generate(data):
    first,last,domain = data
    return [ fl+'@'+domain for fl in \
        [first,last,first+last,first+'.'+last,first[0]+last]]

df.apply(generate,'columns',result_type='expand').to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

the good function to do that is [Dataframe.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).  the parameter of `generate` must be a sequence corresponding to a row.